# How to make a drop down list with conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to make a down list with conditions in Excel.

For example:
If I pick from one list the country "A" I would like to be able to select on the next down list the products related to that country ("1", "2"; "3") and if I pick the country "B" I would like to be able to select on the next down list the products related to that country ("5", "6","7").

For now I have the down list of the countries and the other down list appears with all the products, I don't know how to do that condition by country.

Thanks!